Android app unpins itself on Samsung tablet
I have an issue with my Samsung tablet, I have webapp pinned using either Google Chrome or the Samsung internet app, and for some reason it unpins itself after some time. I tried to pin other websites such as Amazon or LinkedIn, but I got the same behaviour. I have the developer options enabled with the "Stay awake" option activated.
Any clues what can cause the app to unpin itself?
Thanks.
I have tried using different browsers, checking other webs to ensure it was not a problem with my app, but eventually either Google Chrome or Samsung internet end up being automatically unpinned after maybe a day or less.
Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 SM-X200
Android version: 14
